# Drupal 8 - browser tab title translations for views

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-8

I am creating a multilingual site in Drupal 8. The browser tab title for nodes translate, but in a view the titles are all in english.

Currently, the goal is to create one view page and use a URL alias to direct to the other translation views. I have the filter set to content revisions for languages using the "Interface text language selected for page". On these view pages, everything but the title translates.

Is there a way to force the browser tab titles to translate without having to create additional view pages for each language?

Thank you in advance for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "browser tab title" you mean Views' title, enable "Configuration Translation" core module, and then click on "Translate" link next to your View ("Operations" column, */admin/structure/views*).

[image]

If you mean titles of nodes' which you output in a View, then check out settings of a default prebuild "FrontPage" View, because it works just great with content translations, maybe you've just missed some important settings which you can spot there.

Comment: The "browser tab title" instructions worked, thank you!

Comment: @VividExplorer you're welcome! Please, consider to mark this answer as "accepted" if it really solved your problem.